# How to stream JSON with TNetHTTPClient?

Tags: json, http, delphi, stream

Simple problem. I'd like to send JSON over HTTP without holding the whole payload in RAM.

The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.Net.HttpClient.THTTPClient.Post) wasn't too helpful. This is what I came up with:

```
program HttpJsonStream;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.Classes,
  System.JSON.Readers,
  System.JSON.Writers,
  System.Net.HttpClientComponent,
  System.SysUtils;

begin
  var ReqStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  var JsonWriter := TJsonTextWriter.Create(ReqStream);
  var ResStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  var StreamReader := TStreamReader.Create(ResStream, TEncoding.UTF8);
  var JsonReader := TJsonTextReader.Create(StreamReader);
  var Client := TNetHTTPClient.Create(nil);

  Client.ContentType := 'application/json';
  Client.Post('http://localhost', ReqStream, ResStream);

  JsonWriter.WriteStartObject;
  JsonWriter.WritePropertyName('foo');
  JsonWriter.WriteValue('bar');
  JsonWriter.WriteEndObject;
  JsonWriter.Close;

  while JsonReader.Read do {stuff};
end.
```

But this just sends an empty body.

When I first write to the stream (thus using lots of RAM), set `Position := 0` and then `Post`, it works.

How can you truly stream requests and responses?

Comment: `TNetHTTPClient.Post()` is a synchronous method. By the time it exits, the HTTP request has been sent, and the HTTP response has been received.  So, writing to the `JsonWriter` after the fact is meaningless. To "truely stream" an HTTP request requires the use of HTTP's `chunked` transfer-encoding, which only HTTP 1.1+ servers support, but I don't think `TNetHTTPClient` supports for requests, only responses.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Does Delphi have a class that supports chunked encoding?

Comment: not for requests, no. You will probably have to resort to using a plain TCP client and format your own HTTP request manually.